# How to determine appconfig contains a specific key

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# assembly > app settings > how to check if one exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295293/c-sharp-assembly-app-settings-how-to-check-if-one-exists)

In the app.config, How can I know if it contains a specific key?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
var specificValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["specificKey"];
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(specificValue))
{
    // Use the value
}
```

but if you only want to check the presence you could also:

```
if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys.Contains("specificKey"))
{
    // the config file contains the specific key    
}
```

Comment: your second option is wrong - (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys.Contains("specificKey")) there isn'y such method

Comment: @briler: Yes there is. Look at the example code here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.appsettingssection%28v=vs.80%29.aspx 
It returns a string array and then you can use `Contains` on the string array.

Comment: I'm not sure about your first example is correct. If you have no such key in config file like specificKey as index, you will get exception, don't you?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
if(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["yourkey"] != null)
{
   // that key exists..... do something with it
}
```