# Which file type can I use for importing data directly into a dictionary; in C#?

Tags: c#, dictionary, file, privacy

I want to store some privacy info that is usually in my code to a local file on my pc, to make sure it won't be committed to version control. I want to read this file in my code into a dictionary directly.

Which file type is works to do this with?
I thought about xlsx/csv or json, but I am not sure which is best for reading into a dictionary right away.
By the way, I know how to read files with (for example) File.ReadAllText and stuff. It is just that this plain text does not compile easily to a dictionary.
I am still free to choose any saving format I want, but here is an example of data

username1 - marja1 
password1 - fakepassword 
username2 - marja2 
password2 - fake

Curious to any suggestions.

Comment: This question is likely to be closed as asking for the "best" is likely to lead to opinionated answers. But I suggest you look at the [INI File Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file) or [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML).

Comment: I find JSON easiest for anything like this.  Just two statements:  1st to read the data from the file, the 2nd to deserialise it.

Comment: Thank you, I changed the title of the question and hoping that's enough :)

Comment: Those look like [user-scoped configuration settings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13046907).  For .NET Core see e.g. [Equivalent to UserSettings / ApplicationSettings in WPF for newer .NET versions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56847571).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of options, each with their own pros and cons. Any standard format will be easy to deserialize from with a third-party library, so that doesn't differentiate them. But here's a comparison of what your file might look like with each.

## Simple Dictionary

Simple key-value pairs. XML wouldn't really work to directly translate a dictionary this way.

### INI File

```
username1 = password1
username2 = password2
```

### JSON

```
{
  "username1":"password1",
  "username2":"password2",
}
```

### YAML

```
username1: password1
username2: password2
```

## Object-like

You may want a more advanced model, deserializable into something like the following C# types:

```
record FileContents(IEnumerable<UserCredential> Credentials);
record UserCredential(string UserName, string Password);
```

### JSON

```
{
  "credentials": [
    {
      "username": "username1",
      "password": "password1"
    },
    {
      "username": "username2",
      "password": "password2"
    }
  ]
}
```

### YAML

```
credentials:
- username: username1
  password: password1
- username: username2
  password: password2
```

### XML

```
<Credentials>
  <User Username="username1" Password="password1" />
  <User Username="username2" Password="password2" />
</Credentials>
```

## My Recommendation

YAML has a simple format that's relatively easy for humans to read and write, without a lot of "fluff". It's capable of handling both simple and complex objects. It's also a superset of the JSON spec, so the same parser can read JSON formatting. I'd personally choose that. The YAMLDotNet library makes parsing pretty simple:

```
var dict = new DeserializerBuilder().Build().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(text);
```

## One other option to consider

Your use case sounds like exactly what ASP.NET's [App Secrets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=windows) (aka User Secrets) were designed to handle. Consider using their library, tooling, and conventions instead of coming up with your own.

Answer (score 1):

Use Xml Linq.  If reading from a file use Load instead of Parse :

```
            string input = @"
<users>
    <user>
        <username>marja1</username>
        <password>fake</password>
    </user>
    <user>
        <username>marja2</username>
        <password>fake</password>
    </user>
</users>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(input);

            Dictionary<string, string> dict = doc.Descendants("user")
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Element("username"), y => (string)y.Element("password"))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

        }
```

Comment: Thanks, looks good to me! Will need to wait for some time before I can approve your answer. Never heard of this type before, so glad I asked. :)

Answer (score 1):

.NET has a JSON deserializer built in (note that you don;t need the double quote marks if you load from a file):

```
    string json = @"
    {
        ""username1"": ""marja1"",
        ""password1"": ""fakepassword"",
        ""username2"": ""marja2"",
        ""password2"": ""fake""
    }
    ";

    var values = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
```

You could also do a list of dictionaries if you have duplicate keys:

```
[
    {
        "username": "marja1",
        "password": "fakepassword"
    },
    {
        "username": "marja2",
        "password": "fake"
    }
]
```