# Can't use values from App.config file in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, configuration

I added keys with values to my config file and after some web-search i found out how to import those values into my .cs file for later use. 
At the moment i put the value into the content attribute of a label.

When i run the program the label is empty. That means that something must have happened to it because i statically inserted some text in the XAML.

This is the config:

```
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="SourcepathClient" value="D:\xxx"/>
        <add key="SourcepathWin32" value="D:\xxx"/>
        <add key="DestinationpathUpdatePackages" value="D:\xxx"/>
        <add key="DestinationpathClient" value="D:\xxx"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

and this the .cs file:

```
private void Window_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    LabelSourcepath.Content = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SourcepathClient‌​"];
}
```

I dont get any error, simply the value isnt shown in my label.

Comment: Why don't you simply bind to application settings? As e.g. shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/263956, or here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/845033

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to read this:

[ConfigurationManager.AppSettings in returning null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6606626/configurationmanager-appsettings-in-returning-null)

You could also try to get the setting by index:

```
private void Window_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    LabelSourcepath.Content = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[0];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here an example:

in config file:

```
<appSettings>     
<add key="xpsPath" value="C:\Users\yourUser\Desktop\yourFolder"/> 
</appSettings>
```

in cs file:

```
string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["xpsPath"];
```

Then just put the string in the label.