# How to successfully run/debug NUnit + SpecFlow tests using Visual Studio Mac

Tags: mono, visual-studio-mac

I have a cross platform automation solution based on SpecFlow and NUnit 3.
This solution succeeds to run Web (Selenium) and Android (Xamarin.UITest) automated tests on Windows, unfortunately, it does not works on OS X in Visual Studio Mac.

When I use the command line NUnit console runner OR Rider (JetBrains IDE), tests seems to be working, but when I use VS Mac, it does not.

All my issues seems to be related to VS Mac, the first I had was because assemblies dynamically loaded by SpecFlow were not found.
Someone gave me a workaround on GitHub (`TestRunnerSupportAssembly` key to add in .csproj so that test runner can find assemblies).

And now that the assemblies are loaded, it is the App.config file which seems to be loaded but whose keys do not appear in AppSettings object.

Here is a part of the log I get from the IDE during test run :

`Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/Users/.../Automation/AutomationMobile/bin/Debug/AutomationMobile.dll.config'.`

I really think the issue is because of the test runner used by VS Mac, but I can't find how to configure it appropriately.

PS : I cannot migrate to .NET core, because few assemblies does not support it (Xamarin.UITest for instance).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295293/how-to-check-if-an-appsettings-key-exists
try this and follow